# Access google cloud storage objects via torrent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to access cloud storage objects via torrent?

If not - are there any other services that allow this for files larger than 5GB? (it seems Amazon S3 does allow it, but has a 5GB limit- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html)

Answer (score 2):

No. Google Cloud Storage does not currently provide a BitTorrent interface.